# Importing CSV product data - updating price column

Tags: mysql, csv

I’ve searched but can’t find exactly what I’m trying to do, or just losing my mind... probably both.

I’ve got a data feed, with the following fields: Product ID, Name, Retail Price, Sales Price. Right now I dump this into a Google Sheets file via scripts, trim the necessary fields, export via CSV and back in MySQL but I need the data to go right from the feed CSV URL to MySQL, and correct a few fields.

For some reason, some of the prices have weird values, such as 4728.7376 while others have 282. I’d like to basically trim andything past the decimal point. When I tried that, I have some rows that don’t have any prices (it’s annoying) and seems to break the import.

Any suggestions on simplifying this to pull from the URL feed, fix issues and import into MySQL — which is through Google Cloud, but currently testing using MAMP.  I can only get it to work importing using varchar(100) and need to do calculations with those columns; as long as the value is present.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using load data infile you can push the columns from a csv file to variables and manipulate them please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html. It might help if you added some sample rows from the csv file as text to the question.

Comment: Thanks!  I’ll add some of the same code and data here shortly